# Wiring a relay with two voltage sources

Tags: relay

[image]

Is this relay wiref properly?  If voltage one drops below 40 volts then the  load will be powered by voltage two.

Comment: This schematic is very hard to read, and one of your voltage sources seems to only be connected on one side. I'm not too sure what that relay symbol is supposed to mean, either.

Comment: @Felthry it is a drawing of a real (physical) relay.

Comment: Oh, I see. It didn't occur to me that it was a drawing of the relay footprint.

Comment: Are your voltage sources AC or DC? They are currently drawn like AC, which doesn't usually play with with standard coil relays. It will switch on/off at the V1 frequency and chatter itself to death in no time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you make a bunch of assumptions .... yes.

In particular, when V1 is high enough to activate the relay, it won't activate it, because it is not properly connected to the relay coil. Rewrite the diagram using normal circuit elements (instead of the phyiscal box of the relay) and you will probably see the problem.

But since you didn't state what should happen when V1 > 40V the circuit still satisfies your requirement....

And when redrawing, don't forget to connect both sides of V2 and the load.

Comment: I feel obligated to add one, you need to worry about synchronizing between V1 and V2. If the two AC voltage sources are out-of-sync you can damage equipment. I found this out the hard way on a very expensive project...

Answer (score 0):

As drawn, it doesn't make much sense.  The Load only has one wire going to it, and V2 only has one wire as well.  Should we assume that the other sides of Load and V2 are grounded or not?

Also, you've labelled NC and NO on the relay, but not the three other terminals.  I guess the middle is common, and the two others are the two ends of the coil.